# Using nested for loop to display GUI labels

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I have 10 names stored in an `ArrayList` names.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(10);

name.add(name);            // the value of this is "Zac"
names.add("undefined1");
names.add("undefined2");
names.add("undefined3");
names.add("undefined4");
names.add("undefined5");
names.add("undefined6");
names.add("undefined7");
names.add("undefined8");
names.add("undefined9");
```

I want to display these 10 names in a GUI window using a `GLabel` object. Currently, I have 10 hardcoded `GLabel` objects that accept each individual name string, but I feel this is very repetitive.

```
GLabel showName1 = new GLabel(name, (getWidth() / 2.0) - 100, (getHeight() / 2.0) - 160); // this last integer (160) is the position
showName1.move(-showName1.getWidth() / 2, -showName1.getHeight());
showName1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
add(showName1);

GLabel showName2 = new GLabel("undefined", (getWidth() / 2.0) - 100, (getHeight() / 2.0) - 120); // this last integer (120) is the position 
showName2.move(-showName2.getWidth() / 2, -showName2.getHeight());
showName2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
add(showName2);

...
```

I would like to use a looping construct to display each one. The only difference between each hardcoded `GLabel` is the **name being displayed** and the **position**. The position needs to be **decremented by 40 for each label**.

```
int counter = 10;
for (int position = 160; counter > 0; position -= 40) {
    for (String name: names) {
        GLabel showName = new GLabel(name, (getWidth() / 2.0) - 100, (getHeight() / 2.0) - position);
        showName.move(-showName.getWidth() / 2, -showName.getHeight());
        showName.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        add(showName);
    }
    counter--;
}
```

I set up this nested `for` loop with the idea that the outer `for` loop will create the `GLabel` objects 40px apart and the inner `for` loop will populate each `GLabel` object with a string name taken from the `ArrayList` names.

However, though the outer `for` loop works (10 `GLabel` objects are created 40px apart successfully) the inner one seems to *overwrite each label displaying every name* rather than a single name as intended.

[image: incorrect output in GUI window]

I think this problem is occuring because the *inner loop should only run once, not 10 times*. However, I'm unsure how to then ensure the first loop is run 10 times and the second is only run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip both loops and loop over the `names` array

```
int position = 160;
for (String label : names) {
    GLabel showName = new GLabel(label, (getWidth() / 2.0) - 100, (getHeight() / 2.0) - position);
    showName.move(-showName.getWidth() / 2, -showName.getHeight());
    showName.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    add(showName);
    position -= 40;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I thought it would be a simple answer, for some reason I had my mind fixated that I needed a nested loop... thanks again!